# Viewing PDF's in VIFM with Evince

Tags: vifm

I am unable to view PDF's in VIFM with Evince (my pdf viewer of choice).  How does one do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure vifm to open `.pdf` files with Evince. In your `~/.vifm/vifmrc` add the following lines:

```
command evince evince *.{pdf} &
filetype *.pdf evince
```

The first defines a user command, the second sets the default program for specific filetypes.

The default `vifmrc` (that should be installed to `/usr/share/vifm/vifmrc`) is very well commented and should provide all the documentation you need to get it up and running. The Arch wiki also has [a vifm page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vifm) that contains some helpful pointers and tips.

Comment: I added this to my vifmrc and it didn't work.  But I realized that no matter what I add to my vifmrc, the file is changed back to its default upon opening vifm.  That is, if I edit the vifmrc, and then open vifm, and then look at my vifmrc, it's back to normal!  What could be causing this?

Comment: @George, your version of Vifm is probably very old (might be `0.4` for Debian-based systems), there is more up to date version in [experimental](https://packages.debian.org/en/experimental/vifm). You can as well [build it from sources](http://wiki.vifm.info/index.php?title=Obtaining_Vifm#From_sources). The old version uses different syntax and updates vifmrc on exit.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it by change my config file ~/.vifm/vifmrc like this:

```
filextype *.pdf xreader
fileviewer *.pdf xreader-previewer
```